# Get the width and height of an array of images angular typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filereader

I am uploading multiple images and before I upload I want to get the width and height of each image. The problem is that my function only returns the width and height of the first image only.
Here's my code:

```
async getWidthAndHeight(files: any) {
    const newPromise = [files].map((file: any, i: any) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file[i]);
        reader.onload = async (e: any) => {
          var image = new Image();
          image.src = e.target.result;
          image.onload = async () => {
            this.imageWidth = image.width;
            this.imageHeight = image.height;
            this.sizeObj = {
              width: this.imageWidth,
              height: this.imageHeight
            };
            resolve(this.sizeObj)
          }
        }
      })
    })
    const final = await Promise.all(newPromise);
    return final
  }
```

The return value is an array with the dimensions of the first image alone.
I want the function to return the dimensions of all images. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is `files` already an array ? Why are you doing  `[files].map` instead of `files.map` ?

Comment: yes files is an array, but for some reason I have to set files to [files] to map the array

Comment: Can you confirm that the size of your `newPromise` array is the same as the size of your `files` array ?

Comment: The newPromise array always returns only one value regardless of what the size of files array is

Comment: It means you are not mapping what you are supposed to. Check what is inside files by doing `console.log(files)` in the beginning of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your files as FileList use this to create array of promises and use file instead of file[i]

```
const newPromise = Array.from(files).map(file => {
  console.log(file);
  // your code
});
```

Comment: Good, it works for first `file` because of line `reader.readAsDataURL(file[i]);`. So `[files]` was the culprit.

Comment: @Mohid For future problems, be attentive to your data and check if they belong to the type you are expecting. My first question to you was if `files` was an array and you told me yes when in fact it was `FileList`.